# VB6 forms Conversion to VB.net using VS2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, visual-studio-2005, vb6-migration

I am trying to convert a VB6 application to VB.net using VS 2005 Upgrade wizard. This application is very obsolete and some of the source code files are missing one of them which includes .vbp project file. However, I do have all the vb form files. Is there a way I can build this project and create new vbp file using all these vb form files ? And then open this vbp file with VS 2005 upgrade wizard.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new project in VB6, and drag all the forms in (select them all and just drag them in).  It should add everything needed.

Then try running and seeing if you need any references/components that may be missing.  This is more of a trial-and-error experience, and can be frustrating at times.  But give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Appreciate it! I am trying and will let you know if this works out.